# Object (into Array) variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, object

Here is the code:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->AAA = "aaa";
$obj->BBB = "bbb";

$arr = array($obj, $obj);

print_r($arr);

$arr[1]->AAA = "bbb";
$arr[1]->BBB = "aaa";

print_r($arr);
```

And here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AAA] => aaa
            [BBB] => bbb
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AAA] => aaa
            [BBB] => bbb
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AAA] => bbb
            [BBB] => aaa
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AAA] => bbb
            [BBB] => aaa
        )

)
```

Can anybody explain to me why all object variables (that are in array) are changed?

And sorry for my bad english. I am not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array is storing two references to the same object, not two distinct objects, as represented below:

```
array(
    0 =>  ---|          stdClass
             |------->     [AAA] => bbb
    1 =>  ---|             [BBB] => aaa
)
```

If you want to copy an object, use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.cloning.php), which performs a shallow copy of the object:

```
$arr = array($obj, clone $obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of the class

```
$obj2 = new stdClass;
$obj2->AAA = "bbb";
$obj2->BBB = "aaa";

$arr = array($obj, $obj2);
```

Otherwise your array contains 2 pointers to the same object.  The update statement changes the underlying object.